Drei Werke sollen geschlossen
I have heard the following sentence at 0:29 in https://www.tagesschau.de/multimedia/sendung/tagesschau_20_uhr/video-1395142.html:

Die Arbeitnehmervertreter informieten heute die Belegschaft über Pläne der Konzertleitung. Demnach sollen mindestens drei Werke geschlossen.

Is this correct? I was expecting: "Mindestens drei Werke sollen geschlossen werden".

I've noticed that the subtitles for this show are often different, usually shortened, compared to what is actually spoken. For example "Demnach" is clearly spoken but is not included in the subtitles, and "sollen" is moved to a different position. I don't know if this show is really meant to be a language learning tool; I suspect not, Is there a written transcript somewhere that I'm missing?

It's not meant to be a language learning tool, but it's the only free daily German news show with subtitles I know. If you know better suggestions, please share.

There's Langsam Gesprochene Nachrichten which has full transcripts, but I suppose that's below your level. The assumption seems to be that if you're C level or above then you don't need subtitles anymore,

Thanks for the suggestion. I had heard news from that website many times in the past. I changed to tageschau a few months ago because I got bored with the lack of video and listening only to a monotonous narrator instead of real people talking in the street. However, I think it was a premature decision, given how much I'm struggling with the larger vocabulary, slang and fast pace of tageschau.

This is due to the enumeration in that specific sentence. The full sentence was

Demnach sollen mindestens drei Werke geschlossen, die verbleibenden Standorte verkleinert und Zehntausende Stellen abgebaut werden.

The verb is simply pushed to after the end of the enumeration and valid for all three items.

To answer OPs specific question, 'Demnach sollen mindestens drei Werke geschlossen.' is wrong, the 'werden' is needed. However, with an enumeration the werden can be at the very end of the sentence.
